# How to Publish to MQTT with retain option

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I don't understand how to publish to mqtt with retain option (The fourth parameters)

I know that I need length in an byte array but I've try allot to determine how to calculate my payload message to an byte var.

here is my code to publish once I am connected.

```
String str;
char chBright[4];
str = String(ledBrightness); //converting integer into a string
str = str + '%';
str.toCharArray(chBright, 4);
MQTTClient.publish("/maison/GF/Escalier/stairLight/b", chBright);
```

document ask the third parameter to be an byte

> topic – the topic to publish to `char*`
>
> payload – the message to publish `byte array`
>
> length – the length of the message `byte`
>
> retained – whether the message should be retained `byte`
>
> > `0` – not retained
> >
> > `1` – retained

[mqtt client for Arduino](http://knolleary.net/arduino-client-for-mqtt/api/#publish3)

**How in c++ to get bytes from the message I want to publish?**

Tank you to clarify my knowledge

Comment: Just to clarify: `char chBright[2];` and then `str.toCharArray(chBright, 4);` - you want to put 4 bytes into a 2 byte field, is that it?

Comment: ow! you'r right... good mistake sorry.

Comment: I think I've found something! https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ByteCast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to Publish to MQTT with retain option?

The quick answer is add payload length, and retained as true as the last parameters to publish().

```
const int BUF_MAX = 8;
char buf[BUF_MAX];
itoa(ledBrightness, buf, 10);
strcat(buf, "%");
int len = strlen(buf) + 1;
MQTTClient.publish("/maison/GF/Escalier/stairLight/b", buf, len, true);
```

Above is a rewrite with the extra parameter for "retained", payload length, and payload as a null-terminated string.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

> How in c++ to get bytes length from the message I want to publish?

For a String object, the method `length()` tells you the length.

eg.

```
int len = str.length ();
```

For a null-terminated C-type string, you can use `strlen`, eg.

```
char foo [20] = "bar";
int len = strlen (foo);
```